# Removing img tags from a bunch of tags, in a record field value, peoplecode.<img src = ".abc">

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode, peoplesoft-app-engine

I have a field value in peoplesoft which contains a long description. The description has lot of HTML tags. from those I only want to remove the img tags (//). How can I do it through peoplecode?
And where to write the peoplecode.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a little more information:

1. Is the string in the DB already, or coming from somewhere?
2. Do you want the rest of the HTML and just remove img field?
3. Is the HTML well-formed (valid html)?

Making assumptions here, but if the HTML is well formed, you can load it into an XMLDoc, and strip the img nodes.

```
&arrImgNodes = &inXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("img");
```

For each node in the the array, you can get the parent node and then remove the child.

```
xmlNode &pNode = &arrImgNodes[1].ParentNode;
&pNode.RemoveChild(&arrImgNodes[1]);
```

Then re-export your XML to a string:

```
&strHTML = &inXMLDoc.GenXmlString();
```

or
&strHTML = &inXMLDoc.GenFormattedXmlString();

If you're going to display the code to the user.